# Move Email with ItemAdd

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm attempting to move email with specific subject when received.

The mail is still in my Inbox. I've tested by sending mail from my account with specific subject.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub


Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myInbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item

        If InStr(0, Msg.Subject, "Testing Subject", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set fldr = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Testing")
            Msg.Move fldr
        End If

    End If

ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

I created this macro in `ThisOutlookSession`.

Comment: Why don't you use the [rules feature in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-how-to-set-up-rules-in-outlook-75ab719a-2ce8-49a7-a214-6d62b67cbd41)? No VBA needed and much easier to just move an email by its subject.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, actually I can use rules feature. But I have problem with error message `here is insufficient space rules outlook` when applying to many rules. So I decide to create macro

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have an error with the naming of your Sub which means it doesn't fire

> Items_ItemAdd => inboxItems_ItemAdd

As an addendum: I recently implemented a RegEx filter to incoming e-mails as I found I couldn't easily use rules to filter out some junk e-mail coming my way. This should be able to adapted to your needs (I've added the rule I think should work for you, but it's untested)

> Within the 'ThisOutlookSession'

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call RegExFilterRules(EntryIDCollection)
End Sub
```

> Within a module

```
Sub RegExFilterRules(ItemID As String)
    ' Requires Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim ThisNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace: Set ThisNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Inbox = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Junk As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Junk = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
    
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMsg = ThisNamespace.GetItemFromID(ItemID, Inbox.StoreID)
    
    If Not oMsg Is Nothing And oMsg.Class = olMail Then
        'If FindPattern(oMsg.Subject, "^M\d+$") Then oMsg.Move Junk ' oMsg.Delete
        If FindPattern(oMsg.Subject, "^Testing Subject") Then oMsg.Move Inbox.Folders("Testing")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function FindPattern(Str As String, Pattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim RegEx As Object: Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = Pattern
        FindPattern = .Test(Str)
    End With
End Function
```